# When express and vue js are connected, the default address is accessed

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

Express and vue.js are linked.
I have set up a route and when I run Express, it will go to an address different from the vue setting.

**Vue index router**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Editor from '@/components/Editor';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes:[
        {
            path : '/board',
            name : 'Editor',
            component : Editor
        }
    ]
})
```

**Vue main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import {router} from './routes/index.js';
import axios from 'axios';
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import { ElementTiptapPlugin } from 'element-tiptap';
import 'element-tiptap/lib/index.css';

Vue.use(ElementUI);
Vue.use(ElementTiptapPlugin, {
  // lang: "zh",
  // spellcheck: false,
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

**Express index router**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mssql = require('mssql');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Index</p>
    <a href='/board'> Go to Vue Page </a>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const apiRouter = require('./routes/api');

const port = 8000;  //changed port

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join('node_modules', 'devexpress-richedit',     'dist', 'custom')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(cors());

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

**my project tree**

[image]

Express is 8000 port
Connect to'localhost: 8000 /'and Vue's page will appear.

I want express's page to appear when connecting to'localhost:8000/'
And 'localhost:8000/board' doesn't work

I have one more question. How to call express's html file in Vue?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Are you running the express 8080 port and vue server 8080 at the same time?

Comment: @Jack Yu 
Yes, it is
any there problem?

Comment: Actually, if you run two server with same port in the same position (server or computer). Another will not work correctly.

Comment: @Jack Yu
I changed the port of express to 8000.
However, when connecting to localhost:8000/, the express index does not appear and the vue page appears.

Comment: What is the content in index.ejs? How do you change the express port? Do you restart the express server after changing?

Comment: @Jack Yu
Edited the content of the article.
Express's port can be changed in app.js.
After changing the port, I rebuilt vue.

Comment: Where is your `app.listen(port)` ?

Comment: @Jack Yu
I omitted it in the article above.
It's corrected.

Comment: I might see the problem, try to remove `app.use(express.static('public'));` then try again. You should see the content of index.ejs in http://localhost:8000.

Comment: @Jack Yu
connecting to localhost:8000/, the Express page appears.
When connecting to 'localhost: 8000/board' , the following error occurs.
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "C:\html_editor\DevExtreamTest2\DevExtreamTest\views"

Comment: @Jack Yu
It seems that setting is necessary when moving to'/board'. Where should I set this up?

Comment: @Jack Yu
When Except for app.use(express.static('public')) aboved 
js and css in public folder do not work in express
Because the directory is fixed to views

Comment: It would take some time to explain. But, it's a request order in express and vue setting problem. You should render ejs first, then let vue to render the content.

Comment: @Jack Yu
I'll not using vue together in ejs.
The purpose is to go from ejs page to vue page. I think you need to set the path within the folder differently.

Comment: You could put `app.use(express.static('public'));` back, then modify this `app.use('/', indexRouter);` into `app.use('/ejs-test', indexRouter);` and try http://localhost:8080/ejs-test. The problem is there is an index.html in here `app.use(express.static('public'));`, so the request end here not to your `app.use('/', indexRouter);`. In other word, http://localhost:8000/ match your rule `app.use(express.static('public'));`, so the request end. But http://localhost:8000/ejs-test doesn't match `app.use(express.static('public'));`, it will go to `app.use('/ejs-test', indexRouter);`.

Comment: @Jack Yu
If so, how do I do it when requesting a vue?

Comment: @Jack Yu
Change to app.use('/ejs-test', index Router) and connect to localhost:8000/ejs-test, index.ejs will appear. You need to make a request to localhost:8000 / ejs-test /board_drag.ejs to get board_drag.ejs.

Comment: I write an answer to explain, you could use example to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first need to know how the request flow works in whole express and vue.js.
In your project, you're not running express and vue with same port at the same time.
More clearly, you're using express with 8080 port to host vue.js content.

### Express Router Flow

In express, your request match the rule `app.get("/", (req, res)= >{res.render("index")})`
then express will render the index page for you when you visit the `http://localhost:{port}/`

And after you add "other" word in your rule `app.get("/other", (req, res)= >{res.render("other")})`
express will render other page for you when you visit the `http://localhost:{port}/other`

What if request doesn't match rule?
Express will give you a not found page.

### Vue.js Router Flow

When you host the vue output js (we call build.js here) in express server **instead of webpack-server**.
In your vue project, you setup the vue-router with `/` and `/other-path`.
In these paths, vue will render content of `/` and `/other-page`.

We assume you use express to host the build.js
And we need the html to include this build.js  with following code.

```html
<!-- put this html in project_root/public/{here}-->
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="/build.js"><script>
```

And we setup the following code to host this html.

```js
app.use("/", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")))
```

When we type `http://localhost:{port}/`, express will give the index.html to browser.
Then you could use website, click link which is `<router-link>` go to "other-page" which is provide by vue.

**BUT**, what if you type `http://localhost:{port}/other-page` in the browser, then push enter button?
**Express will give you not found page.**

Because express will give you content when you first visit the website.
That means when a request is coming to express, express will give you content by your rule.
If rule doesn't match, express give you not found page.
If rule match, express give you content which you setup.

In the above example, express give you index.html because you setup `app.use("/", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")))`.

Then you see the content of index.html in browser.
And then there is a build.js to render the content of vue for you.

But, there is no rule about "other-page" so express give you not found page.

### Sum Up

When request is coming ...

1. express decide the content by your rule.

   - Not Matched: express give you not found page.
   - Matched: express give you content by your rule
2. When request matched, it give you html (at above example).

   - bowser render the html
   - html include the build.js
   - build.js render the content of vue
3. When you click vue-router link go to other page
   There is no **real request** sent by browser.
   It's controlled by your build.js.
4. When you type url in browser, then push enter bottom.
   It goes to step1.

So if your vue.js router and express router have same router path
your express will not give you the vue content when you type url in browser.

### Example

We assume your vue output which is called `build.js` is located in `project_root/public/{here}`.
There are two routes path "/" and "/vue-content" in your vue-router.
In your express router, you setup like this.

```js
app.use("/", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")))
app.use("/express-page", (req, res) => {res.render("express-page")})
```

Then in webpack.config.js

```
output.publicPath: "/"
output.path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public")
```

And don't forget the you must have a `index.html` in `project_root/public`.
`index.html` must have script tag including the `build.js`
Then try to put `<a href="/express-page">go to express<a>` into your vue content.

Finally, go to `http://localhost:8080/`, you will see html page which in public.
The build.js render the content for you.
After you click "go to express", browser send the request to express.
Express will render "express-page" for you instead of index.html page.

But, you will find express give you not found page after you type `http://localhost:{port}/vue-router` in browser and push enter button.
So, how to fix it?

Add the new rule in the end.

```
app.use("/", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")))
app.use("/express-page", (req, res) => {res.render("express-page")})
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public"))) // here
```

According our sum up step flow, express doesn't have "vue-router" rule.
But, there is a rule which match any request.
`app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")))`

So, express will give you index.html
Then build.js will render "vue-router" content for you because vue will get the url to render content by vue-router setting.